# How to decrypt and record mpd (dash) Live Streaming videos in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming, drm, mpeg-dash, widevine

I want to decrypt and download/record MPD (dash) live stream and store that video for later viewing. I have made a demo to play MPD with license URL, but I want to download video data for later view. The stream is using Widevine DRM.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main purposes of a DRM system like widevine is to prevent it being possible to view (other than on the screen) and share decrypted video, so if this is your goal then the simple answer is you can't without breaking Widevine.

If you simply want to be able to download / copy the content to a device and allow an authorised viewer watch it offline then you can do this using persistent licenses.

When a DRM license is delivered it contains entitlement data along with the decryption key, and this entitlement data can include the ability to persist the license for a period of time - this is typically how 'download and go' video services work.